# For what real values of $a$ and $b$ is $\displaystyle f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\lvert x \rvert ^a(1+\lvert x \rvert ^b)}$ integrable?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I can understand why $a \leq 0$ for the function to be integrable. But how do I figure out what $b$ should be. By graphing the function, I can see $b \geq 0$ and $b \geq \lvert a \rvert$ so that the function eventually converges. How does one go about proving it?

Comment: The criteria are in fact different. You need to look how the function behaves near $0$, and "near" $\infty$, everything else is harmless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out by Daniel Fischer, the only interesting points near which should be interesting investigate, are $0$ and $+\infty$.

$\bullet b\ge0$

$$
f(x)\sim_{0^+}\frac1{x^a}
$$
thus $f$ is integrable near $0$ iff $a<1$.

Moreover
$$
f(x)\sim_{+\infty}\frac1{x^{a+b}}
$$
which is integrable at $+\infty$ iff $a+b>1$.

Thus, in this case our function is integrable iff $1-b<a<1$.

$\bullet b<0$: let's put $c=-b>0$ and write
$$
f(x)=\frac1{|x|^a\left(1+\frac1{|x|^c}\right)}
=\frac1{|x|^{a-c}(|x|^c+1)}\sim_{0^+}\frac1{x^{a-c}}=\frac1{x^{a+b}}
$$
which is integrable near $0$ iff $a+b<1$.

Moreover
$$
f(x)\sim_{+\infty}\frac1{x^{a}}
$$
which is integrable at $+\infty$ iff $a>1$

Thus, in this case our function is integrable iff $1<a<1-b$.

Comment: Careful. If $b < 0$, things are different.

Comment: $b$ cannot be $< 0$, can it?

Comment: @probabilitydoesntsuck Why not? The title just says "for real $a,b$", so $b < 0$ isn't forbidden.

Comment: @DanielFischer you're right. I've fixed, hoping now is correct. Thanks

Comment: If $b < 0$, then $f(x) \sim_{\infty} \frac{1}{\lvert x\rvert^a}$.

Comment: Thanks 2x Daniel; I was really imprecise.